# Searching for Event in Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

I am trying to search a singly-linked list that may contain an event (int). I need to keep track of the current node being processed and the two nodes before it (needed for processing).

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int eventnum;
    int eventfq;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void insertevent(node **list, int event);
void srchevent(node *list, int xevent, node **current, node **previous, node **pprevious);

int main() {
    node *list = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        insertevent(&list, i);
    }
}

void insertevent(node **list, int event) {
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *current, *previous, *pprevious;
    srchevent(*list, event, &current, &previous, &pprevious);
}

void srchevent(node *list, int xevent, node **current, node **previous, node **pprevious) {
    *pprevious = *previous = NULL;
    *current = list;

    printf("current:\naddr:%d\nval:%d\n\n", &current, current);
    printf("previous:\naddr:%d\nval:%d\n\n", &previous, previous);
    printf("pprevious:\naddr:%d\nval:%d\n\n", &pprevious, pprevious);
    (*previous)->next = current;

    /* nothing past here executes */
    printf("current:\naddr:%d\nval:%d\n\n", &current, current);
    printf("previous:\naddr:%d\nval:%d\n\n", &previous, previous);
    printf("pprevious:\naddr:%d\nval:%d\n\n", &pprevious, pprevious);
    (*pprevious)->next = *current;
}
```

Output:

```
adding 0
current:
addr:6422216
val:6422248

previous:
addr:6422220
val:6422244

pprevious:
addr:6422224
val:6422240
```

This code should insert 10 nodes into the list (insert functionality not implemented yet). However, execution ends at line 34 (`(*previous)->next = *current;`). I cannot figure out why assigning previous's next value causes the program to end.

NOTE: the struct and parameters for `srchevent(...)` cannot be changed.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].  Post your inputs and resulting outputs.

Comment: Use a debugger and/or improve your debug statements. As a minimum, use the debugger or `printf` to examine all the pointer values. You'll probably find that one or more of the pointers are NULL or invalid. Anyway, we can't debug incomplete code and need a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as already stated.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, tried to implement your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using double pointers within a function can be slow and problematic. Better to use single pointers and set the return values at the end.

Because you set all three return values to `NULL` at the top (e.g. `*previous = NULL`), the following will segfault:

```
(*previous)->next = *current;
```

In other words, you're trying to dereference a null pointer. Likewise for `pprevious`. If you had compiled with the `-g` option, and used `gdb`, it would have caught the fault and given you a message.

Note that `next` for each node is already set up in the linked list, so you should *not* need to set/change it.

Also, the logic can be simplified [and this may be part of the problem].

Here's a refactored version:

```
void
srchevent(node *list, int xevent,
    node **current, node **previous, node **pprevious)
{
    node *cur;
    node *prev = NULL;
    node *pprev = NULL;

    for (cur = list;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur->eventnum == xevent)
            break;
        pprev = prev;
        prev = cur;
    }

    *current = cur;
    *previous = prev;
    *pprevious = pprev;
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked great and is much more elegant than mine. I'll have to read more on pointers/referencing - C is not my native programming language. I haven't used gdb before but it sounds like something I'll have to learn. I'm currently using Minix which doesn't come with a debugger so maybe I'll program on a system that does have gdb first.

Comment: You could probably upgrade to linux (I've been using it since 1993, so I _highly_ recommend it). You'd have to take a backup of your files and restore them after the install, but linux runs well on most H/W, even somewhat old H/W

Comment: I'd switch if I could but I'm using Minix for my operating systems course so I don't have much a choice but thanks for the recommendation!